# IBM - ODM : Updating corresponding BOM when XOM is modified

Tags: ibm-odm

I have a XOM (Java Execution Model) with several bean classes. I've created a Rule project where I've created BOM (Business Object Model) for each XOM.

Now I've made some changes in XOM/(Bean) class. For example : I've added a new parameter in class with getter and setter.

Question is: How to make these changes available directly to BOM?
I already trying updating the BOM (Right Click on any model created under BOM)

[image]

It shows following error.
Cannot update BOM Entry. This BOM entry cannot be updated because its origin is not recognized.

[image]

Requesting rule designers to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify your data object in your project.

In your project properties you can define a "Dynamic Execution Object" and a "Java Execution Object Model". When you add them there you should be able to select them as a datasource for your BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your rule designer. sometimes your build will not see the current reference updated in XOM. If you still face the problem check the variable name may be deprecated.

Thanks 
Khaleel

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Rule project properties and remove XOM reference from Business Object Model and java execution object model then add it again. Once you are done with this if the error is not removed, close the project and open it again. This will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I often have problems with the BOM origin when copying projects. This image shows the properties that are viewable by right-clicking on the BOM project. Select the appropriate BOM entry and the origin, then Edit. The syntax for specifying a BOM origin is:

xom:/myBomProject//myXomProject

[Right-click on BOM project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1hYO.png)